# How to set button to invisible in content pane/container

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, actionlistener

I'm pretty new to Java and I'm just trying to teach myself by going through a textbook. The textbook provides the following code for an applet:

```
import java.awt.Container;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JApplet;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class SavitchCh6Prjct14 extends JApplet implements ActionListener
{

private JLabel response;
private Container contentPane;
public void init()
{
    contentPane = getContentPane();
    contentPane.setBackground(Color.WHITE);

    //Create Button:
    JButton aButton = new JButton("Push me!");
    aButton.addActionListener(this);
    //create label
    response = new JLabel("Thanks. That felt good!");
    ImageIcon smileyFaceIcon = new ImageIcon("smiley.jpg"); 
    response.setIcon(smileyFaceIcon);
    response.setVisible(false);//invisible until button is clicked.
    //Add button:
    contentPane.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    contentPane.add(aButton);
    //Add Label
    contentPane.add(response);
}//end init
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{
    contentPane.setBackground(Color.PINK);
    response.setVisible(true);//show label when true

}//end actionPerformed
}//end class
```

And one of my exercises is to make it so the button clicked becomes invisible after being clicked.

In 'actionPerformed' just under 'reponse.setVisible(true);' I tried inserting the code:
    `aButton.setVisible(false);`

But that gave me an error message and I'm not really sure what else to do to alter this existing code to make the button disappear after being clicked.

Comment: *"I'm pretty new to Java and I'm just trying to teach myself by going through a textbook. The textbook provides the following code for an applet:" Why code an applet?  If it is due due to spec. by teacher, please refer them to [Why CS teachers should stop teaching Java applets](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/).  Find another textbook.

Answer (score 2):

in the performedAction method, you have to find the object being set, so you just write this in place of your method:

```
 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
 {
     contentPane.setBackground(Color.PINK);
     response.setVisible(true);//show label when true

     if(e.getSource() == aButton) {
         aButton.setVisible(false);
     }

 }//end actionPerformed
```

but create the button as a global, so by your

```
 private JLabel response;
 private Container contentPane;
```

add the button

```
 private JLabel response;
 private Container contentPane;
 public JButton aButton;
```

and then in the init method, just do

```
 aButton = new JButton("Push me!");
```

and keep the

```
 aButton.addActionListener(this);
```

This will create the button as a global variable, letting it be viewed by the whole program, it will initialize the button within the init method, it will add onto the button the actionlistener and then the action listener will read for the button, and if the button is considered the source (just means the button is clicked or reacted to action) it will trigger the setVisible(false) method, creating the button to become invisible, and hopefully giving you the desired output

I hope this helps! :)

Comment: I didn't do his homework. He is teaching himself from a textbook, and needed help; besides, even if I did do his homework, he did most of the code himself, and he needed help with something, so I helped him.

Comment: Have you ever needed help programming or are you a prodigal gift from heaven?

Comment: from hell.. no but u tell all the solution perhaps is better to orient him not giving the hole solution, it's a point of view, i think in that way he would learn, giving all the solution dont learn only copy paste..

Comment: well hell is not a good place to be. I'd choose heaven, at least there I can praise my Lord and savior, but I understand what you're saying. I missed the parts about the textbook.

Comment: Nachokk(rude)has a point I want to make sure I understand this and not just cut and paste(This did work, thank you).

The main issue was that the button was initialized inside of the 'init' section and couldn't be reached from the actionPerformed method in the code. But with your fix I put it outside the scope of the init section and allowed it to be manipulated anywhere. Is that right?

I'm not sure of the purpose of the if statement, so I want to make sure I have this right. The if stmt was needed in case I had multiple buttons that triggered ActionEvent e to not invis the wrong one?

Comment: yes. The reason we put it outside the init method was to allow the program to use the variable anywhere in the program instead of just the init method. The if statement inside the actionPerformed was for if you had multiple buttons and stuff you were using. I am used to have a bunch of actions performing, so the if was just a common practice of mine. If you were to just put >aButton.setVisible(false); inside the actionPerformed method, it would do the same thing. the if statement was just my common practice